# Firebase/Cloud function does not fire event on real time database delete

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to listen for deletes on a subcollection using:

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
console.log('listen for delete');
exports.sendActivityChangeNotification = functions.database.ref('/games/{gameId}/attendees/{attdendeeId}')
.onDelete(async (change, context) => {
  const gameId = context.params.gameId;
  const attdendeeId = context.params.attdendeeId;
  console.log(`activityId ${activityId} attdendeeId ${attdendeeId}` );
}
```

Where in the path '/games/{gameId}/attendees/{attdendeeId}'
games is the parent collection gameId is the document, and attendees is the collection I want to listen on for when documents are deleted.

Is this even possible? This is my first time using functions. I did make sure to test using new data that existed after the function was deployed.

Thank for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code accessing Realtime Database, but you used the words "collections" and "documents", which are Firestore terms.

Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are completely different products.  Make sure you're writing the correct type of trigger for the database you're using.  If you're working with Firestore, [write a Firestore trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events).